# How to display data from many tables in .phtml file Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

I displayed data from **sales_order** table in .phtml file, in **my history** page, not yet create table to this information to be on the custom table 
[image]

But I also want to display more, from **sales_order_item**
[image]

and **sales_order_status**

[image]

in **.phtml** page to **my history** page

[image]

If anyone has free time, please help me step by step, it will be useful for me.

Comment: explain me in depth what you want here @kite hany

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way.

> Namespace/Test/Controller/Index/ListData.php

Add below code to your controller

```
namespace Namespace\Test\Controller\Index;

class ListData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

We are using the layout in the action so we need to create a layout file for the list page.

> Create Namespace/Test/view/frontend/layout/test_index_listdata.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Test\Block\TestListData" name="test.listdata" template="Namespace_Test::listdata.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the layout file, we are using block – `Namespace\Test\Block\TestListData`  and a **phtml** file – `Namespace_Test::listdata.phtml`. So we need to create both.

> Create Namespace/Test/Block/TestListData.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Test\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Namespace\Test\Model\TestFactory;
/**
 * Test List block
 */
class TestListData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TestFactory $test
    ) {
        $this->_test = $test;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Simple Custom Module List Page'));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getTestCollection()
    {
        $test = $this->_test->create();
        $collection = $test->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Setting a page title and getting the collection of our custom module in getTestCollection() function. We will return this collection from here so we can use it in our **listdata.phtml** file for the list page.

> Your phtml file Namespace/Test/view/frontend/templates/listdata.phtml

```
<?php
    $collection = $this->getTestCollection();
?>
<table class="data table" id="test-data-table">
    <caption class="table-caption">Vky Test Data</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="col title">Title</th>
            <th scope="col" class="col author">Author</th>
            <th scope="col" class="col content">Content</th>
            <th scope="col" class="col created_at">Created At</th>
            <th scope="col" class="col actions">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($collection as $key => $data): ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="Title" class="col title"><?php echo $data->getTitle(); ?></td>
                <td data-th="Author" class="col author"><?php echo $data->getAuthor(); ?></td>
                <td data-th="Content" class="col content"><?php echo $data->getContent(); ?></td>
                <td data-th="Date" class="col created_at"><?php echo $data->getCreatedAt(); ?></td>
                <td data-th="Actions" class="col actions">
                    <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'test/index/view/id/'.$data->getTestId(); ?>" class="action view">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> php bin/magento cache:flush

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Chirag Patel. I have to try to do like your comment and change some name of folder link, but it doesn't work