# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to show data in sale_order table.
I follow this guide: [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278978/how-to-display-data-from-many-tables-in-phtml-file-magento-2-3)

And I got the error is: [image]

My files are: 
[image]

And: 
[image]
**Can anyone help?? Thanks!**

Comment: try to change the loop like `foreach($collection as $coll)` then change all the names in the loop like `$collection->getTitile()` to `$coll->getTitile()` Inshallah it will work for you

Comment: Thank you @Asad Khan. I tried but it still doesn't work. Anything else I was wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Change Your foreach arguments,

```
foreach($collection as $col) {
       /*Your logic*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not suppose to use the same parameter name in your **`foreach`**, try to use other variable name like **`$data or $item`**:

```
<?php foreach ($collection as $data): ?>
        <tr>
            ...
            <td data-th="Title" class="col title"><?php echo $data->getTitle(); ?></td>                
            ...
       </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```